# Change kerning for specific letter combinations P- and P--

Tags: kerning

I'm looking for an easy way to globally change the kerning for the following character pairs:

P- and P--

I am using bitstream-charter as a font through the mathdesign package and the hyphen is slipping under the round part of the letter P, which is ugly in my opinion.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
    P- P--
\end{document}
```

Is there a quick and easy fix?

Comment: That's a decision of the font designer. You'd need to change all font metrics.

Comment: You could make a manual adjustment with an italic correction: `P\/-`.  A null group might also work" `P{}-`.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton , both solutions do what I want. Not quiet as elegant as I was hoping for, but helpful anyway.

Comment: Those are the "accepted" methods for avoiding ligaturing between, e.g., "ff" or "fl".  But in those cases, the `{}` doesn't persist if a word goes a second time through line-breaking (as in a heading or caption carried through to a TOC of LOF).  Keep at this long enough and you gain a lot of seemingly useless knowledge.